# How to make Interactive Display Window with using kinect

Tags: c#, kinect, tracking, interactive, head

I want to do something like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFgvNMN2DiQ&feature=related

I wanna track head with kinect and when its goes to left reverse the video when it stops pause the video on the right play the video.Can anyone help me with sample or useful tutorial for this ? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer:) Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

first go thorough simple application example to access kinect data there are tutorials on getting started with kinect in here 
http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Getting-started-with-Kinect-development-quickly-with-the-Kinect-for-Windows-Quickstart-Series

starting in this skeletal Tracking example you will see the way you have to access the kinect joints, in example they use left and right hand and **HEAD**!!, so you then need to access a video player of your choice and get the api to access scrolling bar and then bind the head's X coordinates to player's scroll position.

cheers!!..